# Como ver as colunas de uma visão do sistema no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom eu venho da cultura Oracle e quero aprender sobre SQL Server.
Gostaria de saber como vejo as colunas de uma visão do sistema, por exemplo:
Eu tentei com

`sp_help teste.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`

e

`desc teste.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`

para tentar visualizar as colunas dessa visão que mostra as rotinas do banco de dados teste mas não obtive nenhum sucesso, como faço a consulta desses meta dados?

Comment: o comando que mostra as definições é o `sp_helptext`, tentou com ele?

Comment: Não funcionou também.

Comment: Acho que o @RicardoPontual quis dizer `sp_help <nome da tabela/view>` (acho que no seu caso `sp_help routines`). Eu conheço pouco do Oracle, mas parece que ele trata os _schemas_ um pouco diferente do Sql Server. Se `teste` for o nome do seu schema, pode colocá-lo na frente do nome assim: `sp_help teste.routines`.

Comment: O `sp_helptext` seria para ver a definição da `view`, `store procedure`, `trigger`...

Answer (score 2):

Experimente assim (estou a supor que o nome da `VIEW` é `teste`):

```
SELECT      AO.name AS [View Name]
        ,   AC.name AS [Column Name]
        ,   ST.name AS [Type]
FROM        sys.all_objects AO
INNER JOIN  sys.all_columns AC  ON  AC.object_id        = AO.object_id
INNER JOIN  sys.types       ST  ON  AC.system_type_id   = ST.system_type_id 
                                AND AC.user_type_id     = ST.user_type_id
WHERE       AO.type = 'V'
        AND AO.name = 'teste'
ORDER BY    AC.name
```